# Laravel 8 how to name a group

Tags: php, laravel

This question has been asked but it's outdated in most answers I saw.

This is what I'm trying:

```
Route::prefix('cart')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/mycart','App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController@mycart')->name('mycart');
  Route::get('/checkout','App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController@checkout')->name('checkout');
})->name('cart');
```

I'd like to name the group and then in my blade be able to do:

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() != 'individual_product')
```

The above gives me this error: `Call to a member function name() on null`

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: u can use name-prefixes  see this : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can configure everything with arrays:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'cart', 'name' => 'cart.'], function() {
    Route::get('/index',    ['as' => 'index',    'uses' => 'CartController@index']);
    Route::get('/checkout', ['as' => 'checkout', 'uses' => 'CartController@checkout']);
});
```

And `'as' => 'cart.index'` might still be more readable than a [named group](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes) (it may depend).

---

In Blade one can also use [`Route`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html):

```
@if (Route::has('cart')) @endif
@if (Route::has('cart.index')) @endif
```

---

Listing all defined routes is being supported:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: if I add named routes to each route in the group does it change anything?  I tried it with Route::has('cart') but I have named routes in the group and it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @FabricioG Commonly, one groups per middleware... just see what name (or grouped name) you are getting from the current route: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route ...the prefix is being prepended to the path; when getting a named route, this also provides it's URL.

Comment: You could also set a breakpoint inside class [`Route`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `name` prefixes like below:

```
Route::name('cart.')->prefix('cart')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/mycart','App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController@mycart')->name('mycart');
  Route::get('/checkout','App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController@checkout')->name('checkout');
});
```

for more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes

in blade you can check

```
@if(request()->routeIs('cart.*')) // or ->routeIs('cart.mycart')
@endif
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-the-request-path